# owl-carousel not working in mobile browser

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

my owl carousel code working in desktop browser but it does not working in mobile browser.
this is my plugin code-

```
  $("#owl-slider").owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:0,
    nav:true,
    autoplay:true,
    dots: true,
    transitionStyle: 'fade',
    autoplayTimeout:3000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    video:true,
    lazyLoad:true,
    center:true,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
    0:{
    items:1
    },
    600:{
    items:1
    },
    1000:{
    items:1
    }
    }

});
```

Comment: Which `browser`? which `os`?

Comment: Create code snippet with full code.

Comment: all mobile browser and all os(android and ios both)